# Best way to add check for AAA-pattern to Spock test

Tags: testing, groovy, spock

In our team we agreed, to use the [AAA-pattern](https://methodpoet.com/aaa-in-unit-testing/) in unit tests.
This idea should be supported by a checker tool with these requirements:

Every test should have only the sections

- *given*
- *when*
- *then*

and the *when* section must contain exact one line.

**example good test**

```groovy
def "calculator summs up two numbers" () {
    given:
    int a = 5
    int b = 3
    Calculator c = new Calculator()
    
    when:
    int sum = c.calcSum(a, b)
    
    then:
    sum == a + b
}
```

**example bad test (more than one line in when)**

```groovy
def "calculator summs up two numbers" () {
    given:
    int a = 5
    int b = 3
    
    when:
    Calculator c = new Calculator()
    int sum = c.calcSum(a, b)
    
    then:
    sum == a + b
}
```

**example bad test (several when and then sections)**

```groovy
def "calculator summs up two numbers" () {
    given:
    int sum
    Calculator c = new Calculator()
    
    when:
    sum = c.calcSum(3, 7)
    
    then:
    sum == 10

    when:
    sum = c.calcSum(7, 7)
    
    then:
    sum == 14
}
```

On top, it would be nice, to have a migration path for legacy tests, which might violate the aaa-patern rule.
Something like an annotation @AAAPatternViolation.

**example bad test, which is accepted due to annotation**

```groovy
@AAAPatternViolation("refactor this test")
def "calculator summs up two numbers" () {
    given:
    int a = 5
    int b = 3
    
    when:
    Calculator c = new Calculator()
    int sum = c.calcSum(a, b)
    
    then:
    sum == a + b
}
```

I tried with text analysis and regular expression of spock source code and got quite good results. But implementing an Annotation with this approach would make the code more fragile.
So I have the feeling, there must be a better approach to verify the usage of the pattern in spock tests.

I also read some documentation about groovy abstract syntax tree (AST) analysis, but it seemed to complicated for this relative simple check (especially with my low knowlesge with this kind of programming).

So my question is, is there a better way to make this extension of Spock tests?

Comment: "_when section must contain exact one line._" isn't what the spec you linked to says... It says "_You can usually do this with one line of code._", and "usually" is a long way from "must"

Comment: Thank you Tim for the comment. You are right. 
In fact I want to follow the suggestion of Vladimir Khorikov's great book 
"Unit Testing - Principles, Practices, and Patterns", chp. 3.1.1

Comment: [Vladimir Khorikov, "Unit Testing - Principles, Practices, and Patterns", chp. 3.1.1](https://www.manning.com/books/unit-testing).
He recommends this restriction to make the focus of the test absolutely clear.
During usage of this pattern, I learned that there are rare cases, where strict enforcing of the pattern becomes annoying. 
This is the reason, why I want to have a kind of annotation for tests, which seem to require more than one line in when section.

Comment: I would suggest using code reviews instead of a check for this kind of thing. With the given-when-then separation you are already on a good way to well structured tests. Either your code base will have a lot of violations, in which case you probably won't fix all problems at once, or it doesn't in which case you probably don't need this check in the first place. You also run into such problems as one-line or one expression, e.g. when putting the arguments on new lines for better readability, or a fluid interface invocation.

Comment: Moreover, while brief `when` sections often make sense, there will always be cases in which it would be counter-productive to enforce it. The same is true for multiple subsequent `when`, `then` pairs. If the test needs to [verify invocation order](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.4-M1/all_in_one.html#_invocation_order_2), you might need that, or maybe something like `when`, `then`, `then`.

Answer (score 0):

We do code reviews and then we use CodeNarc (https://codenarc.org/) for finding defects, bad practices etc. in our production and test code.

They have quite a few rules (https://codenarc.org/codenarc-rule-index.html) so you probably won't have to write you own, but if you do, there is a nice Youtube video introducing howto do that (using AST): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZPu8FaZZwRw

CodeNarc generates a rapport with its findings so you wouldn't need custom annotations for keeping track of violations.